# BackgroundWorker not working with TeamCity NUnit runner

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, teamcity, backgroundworker

I'm using NUnit to test View Models in a WPF 3.5 application and I'm using the `BackgroundWorker` class to execute asynchronous commands.The unit test are running fine with the NUnit runner or ReSharper runner but fail on TeamCity 5.1 server.

How is it implemented :

I'm using a `ViewModel` property named `IsBusy` and set it to false on `BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted` event. In my test I'm using this method to wait for the BackgroundWorker to finish :

```
protected void WaitForBackgroundOperation(ViewModel viewModel)
{
    Console.WriteLine("WaitForBackgroundOperation 1");
    int count = 0;
    while (viewModel.IsBusy)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("WaitForBackgroundOperation 2");
        RunBackgroundWorker();
        Console.WriteLine("WaitForBackgroundOperation 3");

        if (count++ >= 100)
        {
            Assert.Fail("Background operation too long");
        }
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        Console.WriteLine("WaitForBackgroundOperation 4");
    }
}

private static void RunBackgroundWorker()
{
    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new ThreadStart(delegate { }));
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
}
```

Well, sometimes it works and sometimes it hangs the build. I suppose it's the `Application.DoEvents()`  but I don't know why...

**Edit:** I added some traces (see code above) and in the log I have :

```
WaitForBackgroundOperation 1 
WaitForBackgroundOperation 2 
WaitForBackgroundOperation 2 
WaitForBackgroundOperation 2
...
```

How is it possible ?!

Answer (score 0):

You are launching a bunch of background tasks, one per second.  Move the RunBackgroundWorker above the loop.

```
protected void WaitForBackgroundOperation(ViewModel viewModel)
{
    Console.WriteLine("WaitForBackgroundOperation 1");
    RunBackgroundWorker();
    Thread.Sleep(100); // wait for thread to set isBusy, may not be needed
    int count = 0;
    while (viewModel.IsBusy)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("WaitForBackgroundOperation 2");
        if (count++ >= 100)
        {
            Assert.Fail("Background operation too long");
        }
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("WaitForBackgroundOperation 3");
    }
}

private static void RunBackgroundWorker()
{
    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new ThreadStart(delegate { }));
}
```

The DoEvents should not be needed.